# Routing sounds to and from my computer

Tags: mixer, usb, computer, multichannel

I know this might sound very basic to most of you, but I haven't been able to find an answer to this question yet.

**How can I route my sounds to and from (mainly from) my computer?**

I recently purchased a Behringer Xenyx X1222USB, so I have a couple channels ready for use.

**Do I have to use an additional soundcard and a cable from soundcard to mixer to get my audio from the PC to a dedicated channel on my mixer?**

I can make any sound coming from an input device (mic, guitar, bass) go into my computer and out of my speakers, but I cannot make sounds FROM my computer come out as a channel. Only as USB/2-Track with a single fader.

**edit01:**
I'm thinking something along these lines:
[image: something like this]

**edit02:**
As I understand it, I have 2 monitor channels (stereo) and 2 fx-send channels (again stereo).
Or how does monitor mix, aux-send and fx-send work?

Comment: I think I found the way I was looking for. Just for confirmation, is this possible?
Mic 1 and 2 are in Channels 1 and 2 and go into both main and monitor mix.
Sound from my computer via stereo jack comes into the mixer's main and monitor mix.
My headphones are connected in the monitor port
Main mix goes via USB into my computer and into my DAW.
Correct? I'm using this system for podcasts and the like, but I bought it so I can connect my instruments as well if needed.

Comment: Concerning the podcast, I sometimes use Skype and I want to route the sound from Skype to the mixer as well as from the mic through the mixer back to Skype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no.  Your DAW will have the ability to route signals to and from the interface as is.  Each channel strip in the DAW can have sends and receives, same for the monitor channel.  For example if your DAW has a monitor channel that automatically receives solos, you route that monitor channel to a hardware output on the USB interface.  The exact way of doing this will vary from program to program, but you should just be looking for the sends and receives for each channel/bus/matrix in your software.

Comment: my DAW, huh? I have Audacity, Reaper, FL Studio and that thing that came with my mixer, Tracktion.
I still mainly use Audacity or Reaper for recording, so those would be my DAWs of choice.